# Error iterating the query results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a context called companyContext. There are Three tables Reports,Logs and Employees.I am given a case id and I need to get a list of all the employees who belong to a certain case (and a log if there is one, but i dont need to worry about that yet). So I made a query get all the employees where EmployeeID is equal to Employee.ID, where the Reports CaseID is eaual to case.id. However, its not reutning a list, its returning a   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable}]

Am I making the query correctly ? Thanks guys.

```
var employees  = await context.Reports.Include(s => s.Employee)
.ThenInclude(e => e.ID)
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(r => r.CaseID == Case.Id);
```

Models

```
public class Log
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Input { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }

}
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Report> Reports { get; set; }

}
public class Report
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CaseID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeD { get; set; }
    public int? LogID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Log Log { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question properly and you want employees themselves, you could start with them and then narrow via the `Employee` class's `.Reports` navigation property.

```
var employees = await context.Employees.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(e => e.Reports.Any(r => r.CaseID == case.Id))
  .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

> SingleOrDefaultAsync

throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

So you should not be using SingleOrDefaultAsync if you expect multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

So entity is actually like using a real database. I had to do a where and select clause, but also a toList to convert it into something readable.

```
var employees  = await context.Reports.Where(r => r.CaseID == Case.Id);
.Select(r => r.Employee)
.ToList();
```

Comment: You should use `.ToListAsync()` otherwise your query will be performed synchronously and block the thread for other requests. Generally, when you build LINQ queries, they are not getting executed until you request a result (i.e. `SingleOrDefault()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()` or when you iterate over a `IQueryable<T>` in a foreach loop (beware, runs synchronously too